# $x_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n+1}+x_n}{1+a_{n+1}x_n}$ then value of $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let ($a_n$) be a sequence with $a_n \in(\frac{1}{2},1)$ for all $n\geq0$ Define the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ by $x_0=a_0$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n+1}+x_n}{1+a_{n+1}x_n}$. Does the sequence diverge? If not what are the possible value of $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x_n$?

I can connect the sequence with the hyperbolic tan function but I failed to proceed further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x_n=\tanh(y_n) ;\ a_n=\tanh(b_n)$$

Then we have $$y_{n+1}=y_n+b_{n+1} $$

Since $b_{n+1}>\tanh^{-1}(1/2)>0$, then $y_{n+1}>y_n+\tanh^{-1}(1/2)$

So $y_n\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore $x_n\rightarrow1$

Comment: I'm dealing with the test of the International Mathematics Competition for University Students, 2011, and I've had a lot of difficulties, so I hope someone could help me to discuss the questions. I've posted the question 2 (first day) before, in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924555/real-matrix-a-3-times-3-such-that-operatornametra-0-and-a2at-i and this one is the question 1 (second day). Sorry, I couldn't urdestand your answer. What are $y_n,b_n$?

Comment: The only thing I could get before: Note that, for $n\geq1$,

$\dfrac{1/2+x_n}{1+x_n}<x_{n+1}<\dfrac{1+x_n}{1+x_n/2}$

So, if the sequence converges to $L$, we have

$\dfrac{1/2+L}{1+L}<L<\dfrac{1+L}{1+L/2}$

It means

i) $\dfrac{1}{2}+L<L+L^2$
 $L^2>\dfrac{1}{2}$
$L>\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}$

ii) $L<\dfrac{1+L}{1+L/2}$
$L+L^2/2<1+L$
$L^2<2$
$L<\sqrt2$

So, if the sequence converges, its limite is in $\bigg(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2},\sqrt2\bigg)$.

Comment: @Na'omi $y_n$ and $b_n$ are new sequences I defined to make the problem easier.  
I defined them implicitly but an explicit definition $y_n = \tanh^{-1} (x_n)$, $b_n = \tanh^{-1} (a_n)$ works just as well.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think I understood about what you did, but I confess that I couldn't understand WHY you did it. Why did you and the autor of post decide use hyperbolic tangent in here? Maybe could you indicate to me some material ou give some clue about that? I know only the basic about the hyperbolic functions, I confess that I never would be able to get this relation here. Thanks again.

Comment: @Na'omi I chose it because I know that $\tanh(a+b) = \frac{\tanh(a)  +\tanh(b)}{1+\tanh(a)\tanh(b)}$. So it was the first thing I tried. Here's a simpler example to get a better idea. Suppose we had $x_{n+1} = x_n a_n$. If we set $x_n,a_n = \exp(y_n),\exp(b_n)$ we get $y_{n+1} = y_n + b_n$. It's easier to think of using the $\exp$ function here than it is to think of $\tanh$ in the original question, but the idea is the same. Even if I didn't happen to think of this trick, the answer would still be manageable, just a little longer. (cont. in next comment)

Comment: @Na'omi You could take your idea of taking the limit, but instead of using the two bounds of $a_{n+1}$ to bound the denominator from above and the nominator from below (or the other way around), you could try to get rid of the $a_{n+1}$ in the denominator first, like this: $$\frac{a+x}{1+ax} = \frac{a+x}{x(a+1/x)} = \frac{1}{x} \left(1+\frac{x-1/x}{a+1/x}\right) $$
This should give you a tighter bound, and hopefully lead to the answer.

Comment: thank you very much, now I could get the idea to use tanh in this question. Thanks for the second comment too, I'll try. You helped a lot. Best regards.