# Real matrix $A_{3\times 3}$ such that $\operatorname{tr(}A)=0$ and $A^2+A^T=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math, trace

I'm dealing with the test of the International Mathematics Competition for University Students, 2011, and I've had a lot of difficulties, so I hope someone could help me to discuss the questions.

The question 2 says:

> Does exist a real matrix $A_{3\times 3}$ such that $\operatorname{tr}(A)=0$ and $A^2+A^T=I$?

The only thing I could get in that problem is that if $A$ exists, so $\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=3$, because

$\operatorname{tr}(A^2+A^T)=\operatorname{tr}(I)\Longrightarrow $
$\operatorname{tr}(A^2)+\operatorname{tr}(A^T)=3\Longrightarrow $
$\operatorname{tr}(A^2)+\operatorname{tr}(A)=3\Longrightarrow $
$\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=3$

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a,b,c$ be the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ so that $\det (xI-A)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$. Since $tr(A)=0$, we have $a+b+c=0$. Since $tr(A^2)=3$ as you found, we have $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$. Therefore
$$2ab+2ac+2bc=(a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)=-3.$$ Moreover, it follows that $\det(A^2)=\det(I-A^T)=\det(I-A)= (1-a)(1-b)(1-c)=1-3/2-abc=-0.5-abc$. On the other hand $\det(A^2)=\det(A)^2=(abc)^2$. So for $y=abc$ we have the equation $y^2+y+1/2=0$ which does not have real roots. We have proved that such a real matrix $A$ does not exist.

Comment: Thanks very much for the great comment.

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ exists, then $A^\ast=A^T=I-A^2$ is a polynomial in $A$. Hence $A$ is normal and $A,A^T$ are simultaneously unitarily diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$. It follows that for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, we have
$$
\lambda^2+\bar{\lambda}=1.\tag{$\ast$}
$$

Now, if all eigenvalues of $A$ are real, each of them must be equal to $\frac12(-1\pm\sqrt{5})$, but then $\operatorname{tr}(A)\ne0$.

Therefore $A$ must have some non-real eigenvalues. Since $A$ is real and traceless, its three eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=x+iy,\ \lambda_2=x-iy$ and $\lambda_3=-2x$ for some real numbers $y\ne0$ and $x$. By inspecting the imaginary part of $(\ast)$ for $\lambda_1$, we get $2ixy-iy=0$. Hence $2x=1$. But then $\lambda_3=-2x=-1$ would violate $(\ast)$. So, we conclude that $A$ does not exist.

Comment: I'm studying your proof too and since I don't have a lot of knowledge in Linear Algebra (just the basic of degree) I couldn't understand your two first lines. Is there a Theorem that $A^T$ is a polynomial in $A$? Could you indicate to me the names of this part of Linear Algebra? I think I didn't study this yet. Thanks very much.

Comment: Why do we get the conjugate in $\lambda^2 +\overline\lambda =1$? We have $A^T$, not $A^*$

Comment: @Na'omi $A^T$ is a polynomial in $A$ by hypothesis, since $A^T=I-A^2$. Then $A^T$ commutes with $A$, $AA^T=A^TA$, a condition known as being *normal*. There is an important theorem stating that normal matrices are always diagonalizable, and it is also important that commutative diagonalizable matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable; hence there is invertible $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}=D_1$ and $PA^TP^{-1}=D_2$, with $D_1$, $D_2$ diagonal matrices with the eigenvalues as diagonal elements

Comment: Another thing I'm not sure about: how do we know that the eigenvalues appear in the same order in the simultaneous diagonalizations of $A$ and $A^T$?

Comment: @JoseBrox, thanks very much, you clarified my mind. I'd like now to undertand your uncertaintes as well. Following your comment, there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}=D_1$ and $PA^TP^{-1}=D_2$ with the eigenvalues as diagonal elements. We have $PA^2P^{-1}+PA^TP^{-1}=PIP^{-1}\Longrightarrow D_1^2+D_2=I$. But the eigenvalues are the same for $A$ and $A^T$, so you post your first doubt (why conjugate). Is it?

Comment: @JoseBrox $A$ is a real matrix. Hence $A^T=A^\ast$. As $A$ is normal, we may unitarily diagonalise $A$ as $UDU^\ast$, so that $A^T=A^\ast=(UDU^\ast)^\ast=UD^\ast U^\ast$. The condition $A^2+A^T=I$ thus implies that $D^2+D^\ast=I$.

Comment: @user1551 I see. The subtle thing is this one: since $A$ is real, the eigenvalues are either real or pairs of complex conjugates, so $D^*$ has the same eigenvalues but possiby in different order (same order iff all real iff $A$ symmetric)

Comment: @JoseBrox $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Taking its conjugate transpose is just taking the complex conjugates of the diagonal elements entrywise. This will not change the order of the eigenvalues in any way.

Comment: @user1551 Yes, of course it does! If $\lambda_1$ is real and $\lambda_{2,3}$ are complex conjugates, then $D=$diag$(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$ and $D^*=$diag$(\lambda_1^*,\lambda_2^*,\lambda_3^*)=$diag$(\lambda_1,\lambda_3,\lambda_2)$, effectively swapping $\lambda_2$ with $\lambda_3$. This is how $A^T$ can be different from $A$, since otherwise it would have the same diagonal matrix assigned, with the same eigenvalues *in the same order*, and with the same matrix of eigenvectors $P$, making them equal (which in fact happens when $A$ is symmetric, because all eigenvalues are real)

Comment: @JoseBrox, sorry by the incompetence that I have to discuss with you two, but in this case you've showed didn't we have the eigenvalues in the same order, just conjugated? I cannot see as this contradicte the equation $\lambda^2+\overline{\lambda}=1$ of user1551.

Comment: @Na'omi Never mind, you are here to learn! For the second question, you should take a look at the spectral theorem for normal matrices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Normal_matrices . We get $U$ unitary, so $U^{-1}=U^*$, but it is complex, $*$ means conjugate transpose, and $U^T\neq U^*$ in general; we do have $A^T=A^*$ because $A$ is real, but as $D$ can be complex ($A$ can have complex eigenvalues), $U$ may be complex. That the eigenvalues are the same in different order does not contradict the equation, since the eigenvalues can be complex. They are real iff $A=A^T$

Comment: I have other doubt, about $A=UDU^\ast$. Can we suppose that $A$ is simetric? (Just rewriting my doubt because I was editing the first comment)

Comment: @JoseBrox, thank you very much again, now I've understood. Thanks a lot. Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

We have $A^T = I-A^2$ , then $A = (A^T)^T = I^T - (A^2)^T = I - (A^T)^2 = I - (I-A^2)^2$.

Therefore $A^4 - 2A^2 + A = 0$. SO $A(A-I)(A^2+A-I) = 0$

Let's call $a,b,c$ our eigenvalues. We have $a+b+c = 0$ and $a,b,c \in \{ 0,1 , \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2} , \frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \}$.

The only possibility is $\{a,b,c \} = \{ 1, \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2} , \frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \}$.

But $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = tr(A^2) = 3- tr(A^T) = 3$ , which is absurd.

Comment: This one is great because shows that there are no solutions whatsoever!

Comment: @LucaMac, did you get $a,b,c \in \{ 0,1 , \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2} , \frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \}$ from which information? Was it from diagonalisation in $A^2+A-I=0$? Thank you very much and sorry the difficult.

Comment: If $p(A)=0$ each eigenvalue of $A$ satisfies $p(\lambda)=0$. ($p(x) = x^4-2x^2+x$)

Comment: @LucaMac Perfect, thank you very much one more time.