# Null sum of vectors over the field of two elements

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, contest-math

I'm dealing with the test of the International Mathematics Competition for University Students, 2011, and I've had a lot of difficulties, so I hope someone could help me to discuss the questions. I've posted the question 2 at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924555/real-matrix-a-3-times-3-such-that-operatornametra-0-and-a2at-i).

The question 5 says:

> Let be $n$ a positive integer and $V$ a vector space with dimension $2n-1$ over the field of two elements. Prove that for any arbitrary vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{4n-1}$, there is a sequence $1\leq i_1\lt i_2\lt \dots \lt i_{2n}\leq 4n-1$ of indexs such that $v_{i_1}+v_{i_2}+\dots+v_{i_{2n}}=0$.

Well, my little attempts was these:

Consider all the sets linearly independent (LI) of those vectors. Once the sets have finite amount, we have some that has the maximum amount of vectors. Supose that are $\{v_1,v_2,\dots, v_k\}$.

As the dimension of $V$ is $2n-1$, we have $k\leq 2n-1$.

Take $v_1+v_2+\dots+v_{4k-1}$. We have that this sum can be writed as a linear combination of $\{v_1,v_2,\dots, v_k\}$.

But we are on binary system and the linear combinations are simple sums. In fact, the constants are only $0$ and $1$. So, we can write $v_1+v_2+\dots+v_{4k-1}$ as a sum of vectors from $\{v_1,v_2,\dots, v_k\}$, with $d$ terms ($d\leq k\leq 2n-1$).

From that equality, we cancel these $d$ vectors in both sides and get a sum of $4n-1-d\geq 2n$ vectors that is null. Is it correct?

Well, we can take the same way and get other smaller sums $=0$. But I cannot prove that there's a null sum of EXACTLY $2n$ vectors.

Thanks very much for help.

*Important Edit (October, 04)*

I've found a document with these solutions and I'm studying them. These are the documents: http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2011/imc2011-day2-solutions.pdf and http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2011/imc2011-day1-solutions.pdf.

***Edited October, 11***

I need a help at the answer of the document above in that part:
[image: Problem 5 - Answer]

So, I couldn't understand very well because $\tilde{v_i}$ or sets, not vector as I'm familiarized. But I think I can get this; however, I couldn't understand as I pass from here to

### "Then, $v_1+v_2,v_3+v_4,\cdots, v_{2d-1}+v_{2d}$ is a basis of $V$".

Could someone explain better or indicate some material? Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like pigeon hole principle.

Comment: Yes, I was trying some of this too, but couldn't get the answer yet. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you've quoted the question correctly?  Picking $i_1=i_2=\dots=i_{2n}=1$ would trivially satisfy $1\leq i_1\leq i_2\leq\dots\leq i_{2n}\leq 4n-1$ and $v_{i_1}+v_{i_2}+\dots+v_{i_{2n}}=0$.

Comment: @user10354138, it's right! It's strange, but the translate to portuguese is wrong... I've found now the original test in English and is $\lt$ instead $\leq$, I'm so sorry and thank you very much...

Comment: I'll give you a hint: instead of looking at $v_i$, look at $v_i-v_j$ (which of course is equal to $v_i+v_j$).  One obvious benefit is that you are guaranteed an even number, so you just have to worry about getting $n$ disjoint pairs.

Comment: @user10354138, I'll try to use your hint. Now I'm also studying the solution of the document that I've posted yesterday, did you see? I'm yet trying understand why the last expression is $=0$. Thanks very much for the comment, I'll try this too.