# Interesting numbers $n$ such that $x^n-1=(x^p-x+1)f(x)+pg(x)$

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, contest-math

I'm dealing with the test of the International Mathematics Competition for University Students, 2011, and I've had a lot of difficulties, so I hope someone could help me to discuss the questions.

I've posted before the questions [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924555/real-matrix-a-3-times-3-such-that-operatornametra-0-and-a2at-i) and [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2939687/null-sum-of-vectors-over-the-field-of-two-elements), and this last is still open.

Well, the question 3 says that:

> Let be $p$ a prime number. We say that a positive integer $n$ is interesting if
>
> $x^n-1=(x^p-x+1)f(x)+pg(x)$
>
> where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials with integer coeficients.
>
> (a) Prove that the number $p^p-1$ is interesting.
>
> (b) For which $p$ the number $p^p-1$ is the minimal interesting number?

Well, I unfortunately couldn't do a lot on item a), and I couldn't even understand the item b).

The item a) ask a proof: "the number $p^p-1$ is interesting". So, in any case, this number is interesting... I couldn't understand the item b).

Particularly, I've tried prove that $p^p-1$ is interesting when $p=2$ (earliest prime) and got the following:

$p=2\Longrightarrow p^p-1=3$

Let be $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=-1$, so

$x^{p^p-1}-1=(x^p-x+1)f(x)+pg(x)$.

In fact,

$x^3-1=(x^2-x+1)(x+1)-2$.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do part $(a)$.

Let $p$ be a prime, and let $n=p^p-1$.

The goal is to show that there exist $f,g\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that
$$x^n-1=(x^p-x+1)f(x)+pg(x)$$
or equivalently, that in $Z_p[x]$, we have 
$$(x^p-x+1){\,\mid\,}(x^n-1)$$

Note that in $Z_p[x]$, we have $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$.

Let $h\in Z_p[x]$ be given by $h=x^p-x+1$.

Then in $Z_p[x]$, working mod $h$, we have
\begin{align*}
x^p&\equiv x-1\;(\text{mod}\;h)\\[8pt]
\implies\;x^{p^2}&\equiv (x-1)^p\;(\text{mod}\;h)\\[4pt]
&\equiv x^p-1\;(\text{mod}\;h)\\[4pt]
&\equiv (x-1)-1\;(\text{mod}\;h)\\[4pt]
&\equiv x-2\;(\text{mod}\;h)\\[8pt]
\implies\;x^{p^3}&\equiv (x^p-1)^p\;(\text{mod}\;h)\\[4pt]
&\equiv x^{p^2}-1\;(\text{mod}\;h)\\[4pt]
&\equiv (x-2)-1\;(\text{mod}\;h)\\[4pt]
&\equiv x-3\;(\text{mod}\;h)\\[8pt]
&\;\;\vdots\\[8pt]
\implies\;x^{p^p}&\equiv x-p\;(\text{mod}\;h)\\[4pt]
&\equiv x\;(\text{mod}\;h)\\[8pt]
\implies\;x^{p^p-1}&\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;h)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
It follows that in $Z_p[x]$, we have
$$(x^p-x+1){\,\mid\,}(x^n-1)$$
as was to be shown.

Comment: It's an wonderful answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

The key word is [Artin-Schreier theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory).

Let $K=\Bbb F_p$ be in the notation of *loc. cit.* the prime field with $p$ elements. The we have $k^p=k$ for all $k\in K$. So the polynomial $A=x^p-x+1$ has no roots in $K$.

So $A$ is irreducible over $K$.

Let $a$ be a root of $A$ in some field extension.
The roots of $A$ are then of the shape $a+k$ for $k\in K$, i.e. $k$ is $0,1,\dots,(p-1)$, because they are different, are roots,
$$
\begin{aligned}
A(a+k)
&=(a+k)^p-(a+k)+1\\
&=(a^p+k^p)-(a+k)+1\\
&= (a^p-a+1)+(k^p-k)\\
&=A(a)+0=0\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and there are $p=\deg A$ of them.

The $p$-Frobenius morphism maps $a$ to $a^p=a-1$.

Applying it once more we have $a^{p^2}=(a-1)^p=a^p-1^p=(a-1)-1=a-2$, and so on.

We denote by $F$ the splitting field $F=K(a)$. It has $p^p$ elements.
Because $a$ is a non-zero element in the multiplicative group $F^\times$ with $n=p^p-1$ elements, we have
$$
a^n=1\ .
$$
This holds for all (distinct) roots of $A$, so $A=\prod_{k\in K}(X-(a+k))$ divides $X^n-1$. This shows the first point.

For the second point, the question is when $a$ (or equivalently one of its conjugates) is a **multiplicative generator** of the cyclic group $F^\times$.

Time for an experiment, using [sage](http://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: for p in primes(20):
....:     R.<x> = PolynomialRing( GF(p) )
....:     F.<a> = GF( p^p, modulus = x^p - x + 1 )
....:     r = ZZ( (p^p-1) / a.multiplicative_order() )
....:     print "p = %2s :: (%2s^%-2s-1) / |a| = %s" % ( p, p, p, r )
....:     # print "... roots of x^%s - a are %s" % ( r, (x^r-a).roots(ring=F, multiplicities=0) )
....: 
p =  2 :: ( 2^2 -1) / |a| = 1
p =  3 :: ( 3^3 -1) / |a| = 1
p =  5 :: ( 5^5 -1) / |a| = 2
p =  7 :: ( 7^7 -1) / |a| = 3
p = 11 :: (11^11-1) / |a| = 5
p = 13 :: (13^13-1) / |a| = 6
p = 17 :: (17^17-1) / |a| = 8
p = 19 :: (19^19-1) / |a| = 9
sage:
```

The pattern is now clear. Let $p\ge 5$ be a prime number, we write it as $$p=2r+1\ ,$$
and we will show that for a root $a$ of $A$ in the field $F$ with $p^p$ elements we have
$$
a^{(p^p-1)/r}=1\ .
$$
This will follow from
$$
a^{1+p+p^2+\dots+p^{p-1}}=-1\ .
$$
After splitting the above as a product of powers of Frobenius applied on $a$, we have to show:
$$
a(a-1)(a-2)\dots(a-p-1) = -1\ ,
$$
which is the formula computing the norm of $a$ on the L.H.S, and the value of the norm extracted by Vieta from the knowledge of the minimal polynomial $x^p-x+1$ of $a$.

The cases $p=2$, $p=3$ have to be considered explicitly, the code above confirms these are the only primes satisfying the requirements in the second point.

Note: The code was inserted to see if the multiplicative order of $a$ drops further. This was not the case...

Comment: This is interesting a lot, I intend study this theory. Thanks so much for the great answer and indication.

Comment: I've studied your answer again and I guess now I could understand, finally, thanks God. I only couldn't understand the code yet, but the answer I understood. However, I have a doubt that I hope you could help me. I've found this document: http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2011/imc2011-day1-solutions.pdf. At page 2, I see there's an ideia similar to yours, but at this context of the document I couldn't get why $x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-(p-1))=x^p-x$... I've understood your answer, but by curiosity wanna understand this answer too... What do you think? Thanks very much.