# Binomial's extensions

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients, definition

In some questions about polynomials, I've found the following formula:

$\binom{a}{k}=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{a-b}{j}\binom{b}{k-j}$

This can be gotten of the coeficient of $x^k$ in $(1+x)^a$ and in $(1+x)^{a-b}(1+x)^b$... Right?

My uncertainty here is about the cases with $a-b<k$ or $b<k$. So I'll might define $\binom{n}{m}$ with $m>n$. Is it zero? I've done some calculus and I think it's zero to maintain the formula true.

Other example:

In one question, the polynomial was wroted by

$f(x)=A_0+A_1\binom{x}{1}+A_2\binom{x}{2}+\cdots+A_n\binom{x}{n}$

So, how I can write, for instance, $f(1)$? It might be

$f(1)=A_0+A_1\binom{1}{1}+A_2\binom{1}{2}+\cdots+A_n\binom{1}{n}$

and all the terms since the second will be zero?

So $f(1)=A_0+A_1$?

This difficulty aroused a curiosity if the possibility of binomials were extended to negative integers as well. Is there, perhaps?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are asking whether or not $\binom{n}{m}=0$ for naturals $m,n$ where $m>n$ or $m<0$, the answer is yes.

Comment: As for the question of how binomial coefficients might be extended to other situations, $n$ can be allowed to be any complex number while $m$ must remain a natural number.  You have: $\binom{n}{m} = \dfrac{n\frac{m}{~}}{m!}$ where $n\frac{m}{~} = \underbrace{n\times (n-1)\times (n-2)\times \cdots \times (n-m+1)}_{m~\text{terms}}$ so for example $\binom{1.5}{3} = \frac{1.5\times 0.5\times (-0.5)}{3!}$ and you have $\binom{1}{4} = \frac{1\times 0\times (-1)\times (-2)}{4!}$.  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series).

Comment: It's very interesting... Thanks so much for these rich comments.If you wanna, post response and I'll accept.

Comment: @JMoravitz, please, just one more uncertainty. In you first comment, did you say $m<0$ too?

Comment: I did, and I probably shouldn't have.  For the original meaning and definition of binomial coefficients talking about the number of $m$-element subsets of an $n$ element set, you have $\binom{n}{m}=0$ for all $n,m$ such that there exist no $m$-element subsets of an $n$-element set, and that would include negative $m$ and $m$ greater than $n$.  When making the extension to the generalized binomial coefficient I describe in my second comment, the binomial coefficient isn't defined for negative $m$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, right. Thank you once again!